# iPhone SDK strange console message launchd_core_logic.c

Tags: iphone, sdk, debugging, launchd

I am running release version of the app on the iPhone, it works fine. There is no error messages in the XCode debugger:

```
Running…
Switching to thread 11779
Switching to thread 11779
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
(gdb) continue
Switching to thread 12291
Switching to thread 11779
Switching to thread 13059

Debugger stopped.
Program exited with status value:0.
```

However I see these messages in the console of iPhone when connect to it via Organizer:

```
WWed Oct  7 15:37:01 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] : (UIKitApplication:com.blah.blah[0x830c]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:2649 (23909):10
Wed Oct  7 15:37:01 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] : (UIKitApplication:com.blah.blah[0x830c]) Working around 5020256. Assuming the job crashed.
Wed Oct  7 15:37:01 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] : (UIKitApplication:com.blah.blah[0x830c]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault
Wed Oct  7 15:37:01 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[6124] : 1 [17ec/1603]: error: ::read ( 7, 0x28091c, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Wed Oct  7 15:37:01 unknown SpringBoard[25] : Application 'blah' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault
```

I have tried Apple's UICatalog sample and empty view based app generated by the XCode. They both report exactly the same message as my code in the console. So this is NOT my app related.

There is no crash logs created, so I don't think it is a crash.

What is it? Is it a problem, even though application works perfectly fine?

Thanks

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem, however my app is crashing on me! There is a "low memory warning" sometimes before these logs, but it is not always the case. Also monitoring the memory over the duration of 15-20 mins using Instruments showed nothing alarming, and the app didn't crash at this point. I'm at a loss to debug this. Due to the "file descriptor" error I thought it was because of some sockets I was using in the app, but this looks to be more generic. Please help. (since I'm facing EXACTLY the same logs, not creating a new question).

Comment: Also, this crash occurs almost exactly 10-12 minutes after launch - which seems symptomatic of a memory issue, but like I said, Instruments is showing no abnormal usage.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and it gave me problems when testing in app purchases. In the end I found out that I was running the program with an iPhone Distribution code signing instead of an iPhone Development code signing. When I changed that for the Debug configuration (and removed the Entitlements.plist) it worked again. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem. I have similar messages on my console all the time. And as you said it's not your apps fault, so as long as you app runs ok there is no problem.

The message is not from your app, it's from the com.apple.launchd. I think that only the xcode console output is really relevant for you.

Comment: Thank you (well, here went 4 hours of my time I spend debugging it :)